# Referencing a dynamic, named range between workbooks

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vlookup, named-ranges

I inherited this data structure. I have a bunch of products and their supplier information laid out as so:

```
Supplier  Order Number  Name  Cost
ACME      00123         A     1
ACME      00321         B     2
ACME      20798         C     3
ACME      11010         D     4
ACME      32333         E     5
ACME      20001         F     6
Babar     20001         G     7
Babar     54687         H     8
Babar     69441         I     9
Babar     65777         J     10
```

I'm going to be referencing this data from other sheets. Obviously, using vlookup on the order number alone will be unreliable without differentiating between suppliers.

My first solution works locally, but I can't get it to work between workbooks. I set up a named range inside the above sheet using INDIRECT, MATCH, and COUNTIF so that the ranges will grow as new items are added.

In this example, I have **Range_ACME** defined as:

> > =INDIRECT("B"&MATCH(Sheet1!$A$2,Sheet1!$A:$A,0)&":D"&(MATCH(Sheet1!$A$2,Sheet1!$A:$A,0)+COUNTIF(Sheet1!$A:$A,Sheet1!$A$2)-1))

(Actually, I'm using another named cell as the MATCH lookup value, but I simplified it for the purposes of testing.) So that I can find the cost for ACME's item 00123 like so:

> > =VLOOKUP("00123",Range_ACME,2,false)

When attempting to use these ranges in another workbook, I get an error that the range is invalid. If I use a simpler named range without all of the INDIRECT wildness, then it works just fine. Here, **Range_ACME_Simple** is just

> > =Sheet1!$B$2:$D$7

[image]

I understand that this requires me to have the workbooks open at the same time. Is there another method for defining the dynamic ranges, or should I just concatenate the supplier names with the order numbers?

Comment: Chris' answer is workable, but I'm leaving this unanswered for the time being. I'd still like to know if what I want to do is possible. If it's impossible, then why?

Answer (score 2):

For a simple way of sorting this issue out and demonstrating what is needed, I recreated the sheets you provided and created named ranges in the data set workbook **ACME.xlsx** in relation to their data column headers

- **Supplier** `=Sheet1!$A:$A`
- **Order** `=Sheet1!$B:$B`
- **Name** `=Sheet1!$C:$C`
- **Cost** `=Sheet1!$D:$D`

Then in the other workbook, I created entry points for the values you want to lookup (Supplier and Order Number)
The Name of the item you wanted to be returned is in the next entry point

[image: Other Workbook]

In cell `B3` of the workbook being created, I entered

`=INDEX('C:\ACME.xlsx'!Name,MATCH(B1&B2,'C:\ACME.xlsx'!Supplier&'C:\ACME.xlsx'!Order,0))` and pressed <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

This gives us the desired result.  Now if you change cell `B1` to ACME, the name of the item changes automatically to F and **you don't need the workbook containing the data structure open if you have the full file path in the formula.**

Comment: So, our answer is: Yes. Concatenate the supplier name and order number.

Comment: Being an array formula, this is very slow. Just applying the formula to 400 cells, and searching through 500 items causes filter/edit operations to take  upwards of 10-15 seconds on my gen 2 i7.